# Class is present in JAR, but still "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, class, jar, program-entry-point, findbugs

I downloaded and installed [UMD's FindBugs 3.0](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) in `/usr/local/share/findbugs-3.0`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/share/findbugs-3.0/
FindBugs.jar
```

I have a little script to run it:

```
$ cat ./findbugs

FINDBUGS_HOME=/usr/local/share/findbugs-3.0
java -jar $FINDBUGS_HOME/FindBugs.jar $*
```

Running the script results in:

```
$ ./findbugs 
Error: Could not find or load main class edu.umd.cs.findbugs.bluej.FindBugsExtension
```

Dumping the *JAR*:

```
$ jar tf /usr/local/share/findbugs-3.0/FindBugs.jar | grep "edu/umd/cs/findbugs/bluej/F"
edu/umd/cs/findbugs/bluej/FindBugsCompileListener.class
edu/umd/cs/findbugs/bluej/FindBugsExtension.class
edu/umd/cs/findbugs/bluej/FindBugsPreferences.class
```

It seems the class is available. I'm not sure how to proceed because `java -jar ...` usually works. And the [FindBug docs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html) tell me to run `java -jar $FINDBUGS_HOME/findbugs.jar`

[What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18093928/608639) is good, but I think I am doing everything the question tells me to check for.

I don't have sources and don't build the JAR (I'm using a supplied JAR), so this does not seem to apply: [Could not find or load main class with a Jar File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13030675/608639). I did try running with `java -cp $FINDBUGS_HOME/FindBugs.jar edu.umd.cs.findbugs.bluej.FindBugsExtension` as suggested, but it results in the same error. And I did verify the dash (`-`) was correct per Max's answer.

I've also tried some knob turning, like removing the `export CLASSPATH`, removing the quotes around `$FINDBUGS_HOME/FindBugs.jar` and removing the `$*` from the command, but they have not helped.

What seems to be the trouble here? How do I make java find/load the class when running `findbugs`?

---

Possibly related: OS X 10.8.5, fully patched.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but `CLASSPATH` is useless when using `-jar`. Did you try without the quotes, since they're useless in this example? Did you paste anything into an editor for this? Does it work *without* the shell script?

Comment: Why do you refer to the jar with 'FindBugs.jar' while according to the cited documentation it is called 'findbugs.jar'? Did you rename it?

Comment: What happens if you use a `jar`-less `java` command, simply specifying the `-cp`?

Comment: @ Dave - I did not know `CLASSPATH` was useless (my primary languages are C and C++). But I tried with and without it (just in case). I think using `CLASSPATH` is an artifact from college.

Comment: @Rudi - `FindBugs.jar` is what was served from the SourceForge download. I did not rename it. If the 2.0.x package is downloaded, then the names are as cited in the docs. It seemed reasonable to swap in the new name :)

Comment: It looks like you got a FindBugs *plugin* for BlueJ... are you using the BlueJ IDE?

Comment: Why not run it using the script they supply?! In the `bin` directory? And Elliott is right, I don't think you're doing what you think you are.

Comment: @Elliot - the [FindBugs download page](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) advertises it as *"FindBugs tool (standard version with command line, ant, and Swing interfaces)"*. Maybe they crossed some wires (or maybe my wires are crossed).

Comment: I downloaded and untarred the tar.gz download to "/usr/share"; `cd /usr/share && tar xzvvf ~efrisch/Downloads/findbugs-3.0.0.tar.gz` then `/usr/share/findbugs-3.0.0/bin/findbugs` started it. What did you download?

Comment: @Elliott - so here's some more backstory... The first download got me a FindBugs 2.x download (not the 3.0 download). It did not run properly (I could not create a new project). So I tried the next 3.0 download on the SourceForge page, which ended up being just the `FindBugs.jar` file. I wish they would move away from SourceForge. Its full of confusing gimmicks.

Comment: I also downloaded v3 from the link you provided with zero difficulty. There are links to the tgz and zip versions, both the automatic and direct links worked for me. Unzipped, get the bin dir, everything worked with no issues. Download the correct artifact and start over.

Comment: Elliott & Dave - I think the solution here was to download another copy starting from the FindBugs page (that makes 4 tries - don't ask how I managed to munge it 3 other times). But I was able to get it to work. Can one of you answer so I can award the points?

Comment: Midwest, actually. I knew of some west coast stores around at the same time, but I didn't know much about the east coast until I moved out here.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I'm casting a close vote as "unable to reproduce" since fetching a different JAR solved it (but the original problem still exists). I'm going to leave it on the site in case it helps others who get the wrong FindBugs package from SourceForge.

Comment: @jww I think everyone got their TRS-80(s) at Radio Shack. I know my family got a [Model III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-80#Model_III) there.