# Could not find or load main class test (again)

Tags: java, jar

*Similar question has been asked several times before but none helped me. Please provide solution.*

This works fine in eclipse but I am unable to run it in cmd(Windows)

I have created an jar file with few classes which have some static methods (no main class inside jar) and I want to import it on an java file(which have `main()`) and run it.

It compiles successfully but while executing it gives error

> could not find or load main class test

both jar file and java file are inside same directory

to compile I am doing

```
javac -cp file.jar test.java
```

to execute

```
java -cp file.jar test
```

I have tried followings while searching different answers but none worked:

```
java -cp file.jar:. test
java -cp .:file.jar test
```

Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Here's **test.java**:

```
import pkg.classname;
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }       
}
```

Here's the output of **`jar tf`**:

```
$ jar tf file.jar

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
pkg/classname.class
pkg/others.class
```

*PS:I intentionally tried giving invalid jar file name but the error is same.*

Comment: Please do not close the question too soon I promises to remove if asked as soon as it solves my problem.

Comment: Do you have a `package` declaration in test.java?

Comment: add output of ' jar tvf file.jar ' to the question. And location of test.class.  Could you show the test.java?

Comment: yes the class are inside an package.

Comment: @Jayan Sorry I cant understand what you were trying to ask.

Comment: The class will be then in pkg/classname directory under the current one.  java -cp file.jar;. pkg.classname.test should do.  Since you are learning, please read about naming conventions.  class name could  be "Test", for example

Comment: @Jayan can you please make an answer,And I will take care of the naming conventions in future.

Comment: IMHO, just delete the question.

Comment: Well, I answered this 7 minutes ago.

Comment: Use `jar tf` to dump the symbols in the JAR file, and then post the results. E.g., `jar tf file.jar | grep "main"`. I had a similar problem that I was never able to solve: [Class is present in JAR, but still “Could not find or load main class”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27951908).

Comment: @jww `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
pkg/classname.class
pkg/others.class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Test.java:

```
package my.pack;
public class Test {...}
```

this file should be in a subfolder my\pack below the folder where you execute the stuff:

```
java -cp .;file.jar my.pack.Test
```

If you do not have a package statement in class Test (or test),

```
java -cp .;file.jar Test
java -cp .;file.jar test
```

should work.

Comment: Well, you called it test - please adjust. And is it really in the subfolder? It agrees with Jayan's comment...

Comment: You code doesn't show a `package` statement in class test.

Comment: `Error: Could not find or load main class pkg.classname.test`

Comment: I tried this `java -cp .;file.jar pkg.classname.test`

Comment: and there is an class called `classname.class` inside pkg package.

Comment: A class cannot be called `...class`.  Please add the `package` (!!) statement to the code in your Q.

Comment: Actully I am making this up,due to some reasons I don't wanna revel the real name of class and package ,I hope it wont matter a lot.

Comment: You can change the names, but please be consistent, don't add impossible name parts ("class"), don't omit them entirely. And don't use "classname" as a replacement - it is utterly confusing. Use first letters only, e.g. foo.bar.acme => f.b.a

Comment: Ok I will make shure to not to repeat it in future questions.(well I just tried to create an hello world program with class name as Classname and it worked well).

Comment: *"Actully I am making this up,due to some reasons I don't wanna revel the real name of class and package ,I hope it wont matter a lot"* - I think this question should be closed since you can't provide real, accurate information. Its wasting everyone's time. Come back when you can provide accurate information.

Comment: SO WILL YOU PLEASE PROVIDE THE package STATEMENT TO YOUR CLASS test IN YOUR QUESTION? OR DELETE THIS.

Comment: A class pack.Classname.test is of course possible. But its (full) classname is `pack.Classname.test` and its simple name is `test`. So if you write "classname", what do you think this is?

Comment: I don't know what to say and how to say but I should  `java -cp .;file.jar test` Worked ,I am extremely sorry for wasting all of yours time,I don't know why it didn't previously probably I was doing something wrong,Anyways Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: You might have avoided answering "yes the class are inside an package." after my question regarding the package of class `test`.

Answer (score 0):

If your main Java class (`test`) is declared to be in package `pkg` and it's *not* in a ".jar", but just a "`test.class`" file, then:

1. Make an immediate sub-directory `pkg`
2. Put the main `test.class` file in that sub-directory
3. Assuming your supporting library is `support.jar`, run:

   `java -cp .;support.jar pkg.test`

Comment: Fair enough, I just didn't know how to demonstrate a long-ish process clearly in a comment. I should delete?

Comment: Yeah, that's one of those Stack Overflow pain points. I think this question is pretty much a waste of everyone's time because Raghuv is not providing accurate information. I'm moving to close the question. Lets put it out of its misery (or our misery).