# Error: Could not find or load main class package.classname

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have three .java files(Main, Convertor and UserBean) in which two(Main and Convertor) have main class in them.
I created a manifest text file with the data:
Main-Class: com.w.model.Convertor

I created the jar file typing: jar -cvfm myjar.jar Manifest.txt *.class

When i try to run the jar file in cmd, i'm getting the error:
"Error: Could not find or load main class com.w.model.Convertor"

I have also set the Path and classPath but it is not working

what should i do to solve this?

Note: im not working using and developing app. Just notepad and cmdtri

Comment: Mention main method class in Manifest.mf..like `Main-Class:package.class`

Comment: is your `com.w.model.Convertor` class contains main method??

Answer (score 0):

What command do you use to run the jar file?

Below is the command to run an executable jar file:

```
java -jar jarfile.jar
```

You can find an example here: [Could not find or load main class with a Jar File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13030952/875924)