# Command line java error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, command-line, jar, manifest

I'm trying to run a project from the command line (Ubuntu 14.04). The main class is called Demo, and I have a Demo.java, a Demo.class, and a Demo$1.class all in the same directory (I know it would be better to seperate them).

I wrote my own Manifest file, MANIFEST.MF, which just looks like this:

```
Main-Class:Demo
```

I made sure to end it with a newline.

Next, I want to create my .jar file. I did so with this command:

```
jar -cfm example.jar MANIFEST.MF *.class
```

Then, I try to run my project like so:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/dependencies -jar example.jar
```

I seem to get the following error no matter what I try:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Demo
```

I've actually never compiled/run a Java project from the command line before, it's possible I'm making a stupid mistake and just can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Here are the contents of example.jar, according to vim:

```
    " zip.vim version v27
" Browsing zipfile /home/ellen/bendersexample2/src/bendersexample/example.jar
" Select a file with cursor and press ENTER

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
AnnotatedBenders.class
Demo$1.class
Demo.class
Demo$ModelType.class
ManualBenders$1.class
ManualBenders$BendersCallback.class
ManualBenders.class
Model.class
Problem.class
Solution.class
Solution$Verbosity.class
StandardModel.class
```

Here are the contents of the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF which is in the jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_161 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Demo
```

UPDATE: Here are the interesting parts of Demo.java:

```
package bendersexample;

public final class Demo {

   /* Some functions */

  public static void main(final String[] args) {

    /* Some code */

 }

}
```

I changed my MANIFEST.MF to the following:

```
Main-Class:bendersexample.Demo
```

And re-generated the example.jar file. I still get the following:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class bendersexample.Demo
```

Could there be an issue with how I generate my class files?
To generate the class files initially, I did the following:

```
javac -classpath .:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio_Community128/cplex/lib/cplex.jar *.java
```

Please let me know what else I should try! Thank you

Comment: Once you created the jar what are the contents of the jar look like. You can open it using winzip or 7zip. I am more interested in the folder structure, files in it and manifest file contents

Comment: @Tej Added the folder contents above, let me know if there is more information I should post

Comment: Please post the contents of manifest file that is there in the jar

Comment: Also have a look at the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030675/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-with-a-jar-file which might help you further to narrow down the issue

Comment: @Tej Sure, I'll take a look and add the info above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just that had the Manifest in the `/bendersexample` folder and the was creating the .jar in this folder as well! I just needed to move that stuff into the parent directory and everything worked fine!

The final Manifest file used `bendersexample.Demo` as the Main-Class, and the jar was created and run from `/bendersexample` 's parent directory.

If anyone runs into this problem I would recommend taking a look at your project's structure before trying anything else, because this turned out to be a very easy fix!